# Cognos Report Studio - For loop?

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I have a COGNOS package for data on processes within my company. They all have a start date, and unfinished processes have no end date. A process is active on date x if the start date is before x, and the end date is after x, or is empty. The package doesn't have a time series.

The company needs a report with the number of active processes at the end of each month, for the past two years. With no time series to iterate, I had to be creative. I created 24 data items, each with the formula below:

```
IF (([Start Date] <= _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date;-1))) and 
(([End Date] is missing) or 
([End Date] > _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date;-1))))) 
THEN (1) ELSE (0)
```

... subtracting 1 to 24 months. Then, I added each on a column on the report's crosstable.

Well, this solution is really ugly, and unmaintanable. Is there a way to iterate a variable on Report Studio, creating a line or column for each iteration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simulate time series in Report Studio.
There are some options:

1. If you are allowed to SQL in RS. Create a Query Subject like:

   ```
   select _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date;-1)) as Month
   union all
   select _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date;-2)) as Month
   union all
   ....
   ```
2. Create a query subject from existing table with dates. Query item [Month]

   ```
   _last_of_month([date_field])
   ```

   Filter it by

   ```
   [date_field] < _add_months(current_date;-24)
   ```

   and check query property "Auto Group and Summarize" is set "Yes".
   Be careful an choose small but dense table as a source.
3. Create Query subject based on any existing table with more than 24 rows. Add a Query Item with expression

   ```
   1
   ```

   Call it "1" as well. Add another QI, call it [Back], expression

   ```
   running-total([1])
   ```

   Filter it:

   ```
   [Back] <= 24
   ```

   Add another QI with expression

   ```
   _last_of_month(_add_months(current_date;-[Back]))
   ```

   This is your [Month] field

Than join this Query Subject with your process list by condition

```
[Time series].[Month] > [Process].[Start Date] and
([Time series].[Month] < [Process].[End Date] or [End Date] is missing)
```

Than just count rows for every [Month]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. This worked great, thanks a lot.